# vba excel : sorting other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Sort command works when the excel macro doesn't open a new worksheet. The same sort command does not work if the excel macro is trying to manipulate a worksheet which was opened by the macro.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Sort
  .SetRange Range("A1:D" & replacementRow - 1)
  .Header = xlNo
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
```

Statement used to open workbook

```
Workbooks.Open (Cells(1, 1))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you have open command? Are you saying that your macro works with currently open workbook-sheet. But it doesn't work if another workbook open within the current workbook window? what other manupulation macros are you using?

Comment: You'll need to change the `Activeworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet")` part so that it's referencing the new worksheet. If you share the part of the code that opens a new worksheet as well it might be easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a link to a workbook in Cell (1,1)? If so try:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Cells(1, 1))

With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
  .SetRange Range("A1:D" & replacementRow - 1)
  .Header = xlNo
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work either. All the other things that I am doing in the recently opened workbook behave as expected.